# Doubt regarding definition of a real computable number

Tags: computer-science, real-numbers, computability

I saw in Wikipedia that a real number $a$ is computable if there exists a computable sequence of rational  numbers $q_n$ converging to $a$ such that $|q_n - q_{n+1}| < 2^{-n}$, for each $n$.

I just want to know if this is correct, because I couldn't find anywhere else such definition.

Comment: Did you find another definition?

Comment: I found one using the "modulus of convergence", which is similar, but not the same.

Comment: Done! I've edited!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Not sure what is the reference you are looking at, but I would say that this definition is rather widespread. Wikipedia cites Weihrauch's book [1] in the end. I may add Pour-El and Richard's book [2,definition 3].

---

[1]: *Weihrauch, Klaus*, Computable analysis. An introduction, Texts in Theoretical Computer Science. An EATCS Series. Berlin: Springer. x, 281 p. (2000). [ZBL0956.68056](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0956.68056).

[2]: *Pour-El, Marian B.; Richards, J. Ian*, Computability in analysis and physics, Perspectives in Mathematical Logic, Berlin etc.: Springer-Verlag. x, 206 p. DM 128.00 (1989). [ZBL0678.03027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0678.03027).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm  studying Barry Cooper's "Computability Theory", last three chapters.

Comment: In Cooper's book it's def. 16.4.1. If your doubt is that in one definition you talk about the distance to the real and in the other you talk about the distance between the elements of the sequence, then you may notice that the two definitions are actually equivalent. Indeed, with your definition, the distance between $q_i$ and the limit of the sequence is less than $2^{-i}$.

Comment: Yes, it was precisely that. Definition 16.4.7 also confused me, because it looks similar to the one in Wikipedia but talks about modulus of convergence, which I'm having a hard time understanding.

Comment: Essentially the modulus of convergence is the key to go from a generic convergent sequence to a rapidly convergent one. In general, if $(q_i)_i$ converges to $x$ you may not be able to say much about $x$ ($q_i$ converges only in the limit, so at each stage you don't know how close you are to $x$). If you also have a modulus of convergence you can thin out $(q_i)_i$ so that, at each step, you know how far away you are from $x$, i.e. you are approximating it and you know a bound on the error of your approximation.

Comment: Now I understood definition 16.4.1, and how it relates to this one - they are indeed the same, I sketched a proof in my notebook. Thank you for showing me. So the modulus of convergence is like a function to control the "distance" between the number to be computed and the approximation I'm considering. Yes, yes, it makes sense now.